# How to listen to range drag events with Ionic Framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, mobile, ionic-framework

I want to listen to range drag events on an app I'm developing. I've tried a lot of different approaches already, the first two I found here in SO:

- angular-hammer (http://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/)
- angular-gestures (which is also based on Hammer.js - https://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures)
- ngTouch which is in the AngularJS documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch)
- jQuery (based on: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2752-using-jquery-instead-of-jqlite-in-angularjs.htm)

But nothing worked. It's like there wasn't even the call for the file.

I'm beginning to think that it has something to do with how Ionic Framework wrapping works, maybe it just locks in AngularJS context and doesn't let anything else enters its scope.

Can anyone suggest me a proper solution to get those events?

Thanks!

Comment: So what you want is to know when an input type="range" is changed? or the normal drag event like touch and the drag somewhere and drop?

Comment: I want the normal touch/drag/drop event. I can get the change event with ng-change, but it wouldn't work because I want to run a function whenever the user start dragging the button, and another one when he finishes, and ng-change wil fire all the way.

Answer (score 0):

They're not specific to ranges but you should be able to use Ionic's [`on-touch`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onTouch/) and [`on-release`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onRelease/) on your input.

And you'll get updates during drag with `on-drag` (same as ng-change I guess).